# Why defense of Hamas-justification in US universities is more prevalent in Humanities than in STEM?

Tags: united-states, israel, education, hamas, 2023-israel-hamas-war

It is not easy to find information about this division, but the two open letter and the affiliation of those signed them, do give us some clue - the following data was [published by Ram Fishman](https://twitter.com/RamFishman/status/1722258229668057429) on X: [image]

I would love to base this question by more reliable data. However, My question is about the *why*: why do we see such notable division? Any indoctrination? Or some professors like Russell Rickford from Cornell (for whom seeing innocent civilians massacred and babies abducted is "exhilarating” and “energizing") have too much influence? Is it kind of a clique that holding certain views helps one to climb the ladder in the Academic world?

**Edit:**

Given the suggestion and criticism on this question by @xyldke:

> 1. Link the two letters directly. 2. Call them "Letter in support of student activism against Israel" and "Letter condemning antisemitism at student protests" or something similar. 3. Remove the reference to Russel Rickford as he is from a different university. 4. Edit the question title to reflect the change in letters and their meaning. Even changing Hamas-justification to "defense of Hamas-justification" would be an improvement.

Let me reply thus:

1+2. [The condemnation letter](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRYUSR01Cb6zV50rDtm88q0ppSz-bn40oJ28YTG5cYJGpAjNF4hkiCAwQKya2iI5h--cb633CbeAtL6/pub?urp=gmail_link); [The Support letter](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cVLg6RTnqd2BTzuouWbfACnFEex7GQeImDZJnMlUReM/preview?pli=1) titled("...Defense of Robust Debate About the History and Meaning of the War in Israel/Gaza..".

3. I do not intend to remove the reference to Russell Rickford precisely *because* he is from Cornell and not from Columbia. As I answered in a comment to a very valid question of why I generalized Columbia. In my opinion that extreme statement by a professor could not have happened without fertile soil in the academic environment. People might disagree, but even if you do, this is another bit of information from another University and is important given the scarcity of information.
4. I disagree with the commentary provided by @xyldke in anther comment that in the "support" letter: "They are basically making a free speech argument", but I understand the critic hence will change the title. But let me explain: behind all the nice words, the letter - at the end of the day - presents - even of course not explicitly (though very nearly so: "In our view, the student statement aims to recontextualize the events of October 7, 2023, pointing out that military operations and state violence did not begin that day,", - presents the defense to present the massacre as a justified action. The authors of condemnation saw that in this and same-kind letter and thus were promoted to respond with their own letter. To make the long story short: The naïve alien who reads the two letter could hardly see any contraction between them. After all, one is "free speech" the other "condemnation of atrocities". **I will delete the question if 10%+ of the people who sign the "support" signed also the "condemnations" letter.**. Those who signed the "Support letter" and then failed to sign the "condemnation" simply prove how just was the condemnation letter in its accusation.

Comment: The graph points to Columbia, is there a reason to believe this can be generalised over all US universities?

Comment: I think the post is referring to the following open letters: [Support](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cVLg6RTnqd2BTzuouWbfACnFEex7GQeImDZJnMlUReM/preview?pli=1), [Condemn](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRYUSR01Cb6zV50rDtm88q0ppSz-bn40oJ28YTG5cYJGpAjNF4hkiCAwQKya2iI5h--cb633CbeAtL6/pub?urp=gmail_link).

Comment: @LioElbammalf, that's a fair question - and as noted I would like to have more information but it is hard to find. To answer your question: Yes. there is strong reason to believe this can be  generalized to at least ivy league Unis if not all US. The profile in other Ivy league Unis is probably similar. Note that Cornell professor - in what env an "honorable" man can express itself like this publicly - I posit his statement reveals more about the Uni then about him. The numbers in Columbia are so strong it would be naive to think it is not reproducible in other Unis.

Comment: I also think it's worth pointing out that both letters do not directly talk about the attacks of October 7 but instead about student activism surrounding the conflict. The "Support" letter says the following: "It is worth noting that not all of us agree with every one of the claims made in the students’ statement, but we do agree that making such claims cannot and should not be considered anti-Semitic. Their merits are being debated by governmental and non-governmental agencies at the highest level, and constitute a terrain of completely legitimate political and legal debate."

Comment: @xyldke the condem letter refers to *"...These incidents, which include antisemitic epithets, physical assault, and swastikas scrawled on bathroom walls, are growing in frequency and are creating a hostile and unsafe environment "* surely that can be considered problematic?

Comment: They are basically making a free speech argument. You could say that they are wrong, that the original statements were antisemitic and that repressions against the students that issued them are justified. You can also *believe* that the "Support" statement shows indirect support for Hamas but that is not nearly self-evident enough to put in a question. Note that questions on this site should refrain from discrediting political groups or causes.

Comment: @Angriffsreiher Sure you can. I'm not saying I agree with them. I'm just pointing out that the question mischaracterizes the Support letter. Some of the authors might also agree with you that these things are anti-semitic. After all they did not defend these actions but students that "express empathy for the lives and dignity of Palestinians, and/or [...] signed on to a student-written statement". But again: I'm not saying the Support letter is correct. Just that calling it a justification of Hamas does not meet the standards of this Stack.

Comment: Unfortunately, my edits would apply immediately, so I can't make a full suggestion. However, I would suggest the following adjustments to retract my close vote: 1. Link the two letters directly. 2. Call them "Letter in support of student activism against Israel" and "Letter condemning antisemitism at student protests" or something similar. 3. Remove the reference to Russel Rickford as he is from a different university. 4. Edit the question title to reflect the change in letters and their meaning. Even changing Hamas-justification to "defense of Hamas-justification" would be an improvement

Comment: -1, both for the reasons mentioned by xyldke—the letters are not equivalent to support or opposition to the justification of Hamas's actions—and because the presentation in the X post is probably intentionally misleading, insofar as the vast majority of the 4,600 professors and additional instructional staff at Columbia University did not sign either letter. There should be another column eight times as high as the others that reads "neither," at minimum. Of course, that makes the assertions false: maybe most of the rest supported or opposing justification of Hamas but did not sign a letter.

Comment: The point is, a question based on data presented in an inaccurate manner in conjunction with a false description is not a good question.

Comment: (By the way, that would be about eight times as high as the others *combined*).

Comment: Also, even if the data were good, it is about one university, whereas the question implies a generalization to all.

Comment: Who is this Ram Fishman person and why should we care about they write on Twitter?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - Ah, well, see, they're the one who showed that one in thirty Columbia University professors supported some letter that was very anti-Israel, thus *proving* that humanities professors everywhere applaud Hamas killing random people.

Comment: Yes, clearly a political and sociological subject expert and with no discernible potential bias:  https://www.crunchbase.com/person/ram-fishman Much worth quoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect nearly all of it has to do with the political leanings of the professors themselves. In general, Humanities not including Econ leans heavily to the left, while the more stuff based studies (STEM, Business, etc) lean less to the left (though are still left leaning). [This has been replicated by a number of studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_views_of_American_academics). I've no doubt there are a variety of reasons for why that is, including self selection, group acceptance necessary to be accepted as a grad student and hired, what students learn and focus on by learning the subject itself, etc. but that is all beyond scope, and an answer for a different but related question.

Meanwhile, [US support for Palestine (not Hamas) tends to be a left leaning position](https://news.gallup.com/poll/390737/americans-pro-israel-though-palestinians-gain-support.aspx). This stacks up with core beliefs, namely anticolonialism and the oppressor/oppressed dynamic. I can't find a study for it, but I don't think people will begrudge me saying that support for Hamas (not just Palestine) in the US is mostly a further left position, where you need either an extreme view of anticolonialism or the oppressor/oppressed dynamic, or some antisemitism mixed in (note the 'in the US' is doing heavy work here. Outside of the US, especially in Palestine, there's a variety of additional reasons). Note that the extreme right also can end up supporting Hamas by going full bore on the antisemitism, but given that their presence in current US academia is basically 0, I'll ignore them from here on out as outside scope. In short, anyone who is academia and supporting Hamas (not just Palestine) is going to be on the extreme left.

And the extreme left shows up mostly in the disciplines that have the highest concentration of left wingers, because there the ideological difference between the median professor and supporting Hamas would be the smallest (note this isn't a moral hit on the median professor, just a comment about what beliefs ideologies similar to the median professor's have. I'm likely just phrasing this badly).

In fact, for Columbia, the median non-Econ Humanities professor is apparently on the extreme left, given that a strong majority **of those who responded** support Hamas (see the poll in the question, it states that 150/243 professors who responded are supporting Hamas, a ~61.7% support rate, but note that the self selection means this might not even be representative of Columbia's non-Econ Humanities). But I *highly* doubt this extends to all other universities/colleges. Columbia is going to be more left leaning than most, given that it is in New York, in the Ivy League, and a liberal arts college. It's going to be one of the most left leaning colleges in America, so conclusions from looking at it aren't something that can reliably be extended to cover most other universities/departments.

So in short, I doubt that professors have a particular love of Hamas, but simply that professors in certain disciplines tend to lean politically one way enough that they end up supporting Hamas. I've no doubt you could find the same for any other far left position, whether the position is good, bad or neutral. Similarly, if you were looking at musicians for some far right position, you would find it most often in country singers.

Comment: The problem is, the question is based on faulty data presented in a misleading way. Before asking "Why is this true?", we would first have to ask "Is this true?"

Comment: @Obie2.0 I linked to a wikipedia page containing a number of studies showing that yes, professors lean left, and humanities professors lean more left. If you have a complaint about the question, instead comment on the question

Comment: @theresawalrus, thanks for your time answering my question. Appreciated. Sorry your answer probably got down-voted as my question which is now closed. I guess  this is the moment one has to say to himself to stop argue with someone on the internet .. lol :) . People now angry I gave credit asking who is "Ram" or saying that "data is shit", but had I not give credit, they would justly tell me to cite the source of the diagram -- data, btw, can be verified by anyone by simple counting.

Answer (score -12):

One straightforward explanation is that students of the Humanities are self-selecting as having interest in humans affairs and activities, and are more likely to have studied things which help them to interpret the conflict.

Whereas students of STEM (because their studies are not particularly relevant to interpreting political affairs) may be more likely to have little interest or engagement, and therefore parrot whatever the media happens to be blaring out at that moment.

To be clear, I'm not suggesting the media is likely to set the views of STEM students deeply. Rather, the most cursory exposure to media narrative (such as enough to connect Hamas with "terrorism", and to see American president Biden seeming to back Israel), combined with the STEM students' lack of further engagement, is likely to cause them to shoot from the hip accordingly when asked for an opinion.

The association of STEM subjects with higher conventional intellect, higher eventual earnings, more expensive courses, more rote learning with fewer philosophical ambiguities at the lower levels, stereotypically male abilities - and Humanities somewhat with all the opposite - may also plausibly produce a bias in socioeconomic background and ideological orientation.

But personally I think the first explanation will predominate - Humanities students are simply more likely to be engaged with the issues.

Comment: This is all opinion, it could be phrased to the reverse and you could claim STEM students are more likely to look past emotive language and interrogate facts rather than be lead along by short social media posts. That would have been an equally valid (and bad) answer. I know its hard in subjects like this but try to keep your opinion out of it and search for facts that support your answer.

Comment: @LioElbammalf, in my view it is a fact (not an opinion) that humanities relate to the kind of subject where these things like Israel-Palestine would be studied, whereas STEM subjects are by definition completely unrelated. The logic is not that STEM students are unable to look at facts - it's that their chosen subjects don't concern the relevant facts, and therefore when surveyed they are less likely to have any depth of knowledge.

Comment: @LioElbammalf Surely it's reasonable to assume that experts on the Middle East would be more likely to be found in Humanities and Social Sciences faculties? I admit some of the answer is tendentious but the basic point is justifiable, unless you want to argue against my claim and show that e.g. biologists know more about politics than lecturers on politics, or the hiring policies of universities select people who know less about the subject than the average person.

Comment: @StuartF Do you think that specific branch of politics is enough to account for the difference between all of humanities subjects and all stem subjects? The split is larger than the familiarity with the subject between, say a health and social care professor and a biology one or a professor of English literature and a physics professor or a professor of French language and one of chemistry. Each is unlikely to have come across the subject in a professional capacity. Unless you have something indicating professors of middle eastern politics makes up a majority of humanities professors?

Comment: In addition to this answer being entirely opinion, it also makes an unfounded implication of higher education in politics means support for Palestine and that less informed and more reactionary opinions support Israel. Aside from that its a somewhat interesting choice to paint STEM students as irrational and emotional about politics while trying to claim its the Humanities students to be more level-headed and discerning. This answer has quite a few wild and unbelievable claims in it, all without a single bit of supporting evidence.

Comment: @DavidS, I don't know what evidence I should have to adduce to show that politics is the domain of humanities and not STEM. I didn't say anything about irrationality or emotionality - I argued STEM students, not having studied any relevant subject and probably being more interested in non-relevant subjects, are more likely to parrot shallow information drawn from the media. And I don't think anyone would dispute that the media is more likely to describe Hamas than the IDF as terrorists, for example.